# How to extend SharePoint 2013 server Central Administration

Tags: central-administration, sharepoint-server

I'm a newbie to administering SharePoint and I want to extend the Central Administration web application so that others can access it throughout LAN or internet then apply some user policy for it's security. I am able to do this on another web application that contains one of my SharePoint site. I'm just wondering if I can do that as well on Central Administration web application using the same procedure (Extend button in the ribbon) or it has a different procedure or if it cannot be done at all. If there's a different procedure, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done just as the same way for any other web application. Double check with your zones and authentication providers.